# C structure to Python class or dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

I heard and read that, defining large number of information is easy using class structure, which is defined in C language (see C Code below).

I want to defined similar way using Python. I need little favor on code, and I am in new learner group of Python.

Any suggestion about which way make it easy to define? Going `dict` is fine, but `class` is best.

Example in C code below (and I have additional similar structures and information):

```c
typedef struct
{
    U16         ID;
    S8          Name[32];
    S8          Description[96];
    S8          Units[16];
    enum eType  Type;
    F32         Scaling;
    F32         Offset;
    BOOL        Writeable;
} sDataInfo;

/*  ID,     Name,                       Description,                Unit,    Type, Scaling, Offset, Writable */
sDataInfo data_items[] =
{
    0x0202, "dtc_num_of_faults_",       "Number of DTCs",           "",      u8,   1,       0,      FALSE,
    0x2007, "FlBodyVertLocSel_A_Meas_", "FL Vertical Acceleration", "m/s^2", s16,  0.05,    0,      FALSE,
    0x2008, "FrBodyVertLocSel_A_Meas_", "FR Vertical Acceleration", "m/s^2", s16,  0.05,    0,      FALSE,
    0x2022, "RlBodyVertLocSel_A_Meas_", "RL Vertical Acceleration", "m/s^2", s16,  0.05,    0,      FALSE
}
```

It is important to know every one the above code can be changed in Python. None of question answered for above in any online chain.

And expecting some examples as well.

Comment: @martineau, Thanks for correcting. Would you answer my question?

Comment: Bharat: You're welcome. One reason I haven't post an answer is because it's unclear to me exactly what you're trying to achieve (and why). Python isn't like C in that it doesn't have something like a `struct` data-type or the ability to declare an array of them such a concise manner. It's also dynamically typed, so variables/attributes in it don't have one type of value permanently bound to them as in C—their type is defined by the value that happens to be currently assigned to them. Please [edit] your question and explain what you plan on doing with the class (or dict) defined.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in a comment, I'm not sure exactly what you want...but here's one guess:

```
from pprint import pprint
import sys

def sprintf(format, *args):
    return format % args

def _attributes_from_dict(d):
    self = d.pop('self')
    for n, v in d.items():
        setattr(self, n, v)

class DataInfo(object):
    fieldnames = 'id, name, description, units, type, scaling, offset, writeable'.split(', ')

    def __init__(self, id, name, description, units, type, scaling, offset, writeable):
        _attributes_from_dict(locals())

    def __repr__(self):  # optional
        values = tuple(getattr(self, fieldname) for fieldname in self.fieldnames)
        id = values[0]
        remainder = ', '.join(map(repr, values[1:]))
        return sprintf('%s(0x%04x, %s)', self.__class__.__name__, id, remainder)

u8, s16 = 0, 1  # enum eType names and values

data_items = [
    DataInfo(*args) for args in [
        (0x0202, "dtc_num_of_faults_",       "Number of DTCs",           "",      u8,  1,    0, False),
        (0x2007, "FlBodyVertLocSel_A_Meas_", "FL Vertical Acceleration", "m/s^2", s16, 0.05, 0, False),
        (0x2008, "FrBodyVertLocSel_A_Meas_", "FR Vertical Acceleration", "m/s^2", s16, 0.05, 0, False),
        (0x2022, "RlBodyVertLocSel_A_Meas_", "RL Vertical Acceleration", "m/s^2", s16, 0.05, 0, False),
    ]
]

pprint(data_items)
```

Output:

```
[DataInfo(0x0202, 'dtc_num_of_faults_', 'Number of DTCs', '', 0, 1, 0, False),
 DataInfo(0x2007, 'FlBodyVertLocSel_A_Meas_', 'FL Vertical Acceleration', 'm/s^2', 1, 0.05, 0, False),
 DataInfo(0x2008, 'FrBodyVertLocSel_A_Meas_', 'FR Vertical Acceleration', 'm/s^2', 1, 0.05, 0, False),
 DataInfo(0x2022, 'RlBodyVertLocSel_A_Meas_', 'RL Vertical Acceleration', 'm/s^2', 1, 0.05, 0, False)]
```